# Read paired arrays from a file in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a bash script which breaks bash array into pairs, and match on either element;

```sh
declare -a arr=(
    "apple" "fruit"
    "cabbage" "vegetables"
)

for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i+=2)); do
    echo "${arr[i]} ${arr[i+1]}"
done
```

So when you run this script, it prints out each 2 element from the array, like this;

```sh
# bash script
apple fruit
cabbage vegetables
```

and I can also choose any element I want with `${arr[i+@]}`.

Now I'm trying to read this array from a separate text file, instead of inside the script since I'll be manipulating this array in the future.

I've tried this method so far, which looked pretty promising at first but didn't work at all;

```sh
filename='stuff.log'
filelines=`cat $filename`

for line in $filelines ; do
    props=($line)
    echo "${props[0]} ${props[1]}"
done
```

which should've print out the below content in the console (basically the same thing as the first script where the array is inside the script), supposedly but instead, it returned nothing.

```sh
# bash script
apple fruit
cabbage vegetables
```

And the inside of `stuff.log` is;

```
"apple" "fruit"
"cabbage" "vegetables"
```

How can I basically read the array from a separate file for the first script and also be able to manipulate the content of array file in the future?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: I'll give it a read, thanks for that! really helpful to improve myself. appreciated.

Comment: before you dive into text manipulation in `bash` I suggest you read up some basic `awk` to handle your future problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think, if you trust your input, you can do:

```
IFS=' \n' eval props=($(<stuff.log))
```

Eval is evil and it is there to remove leading and trailing `"`. And it will parse properly elements with spaces in them. We can do a little safer by reading the file into array and then removing leading and trailing `"`:

```
IFS=' \n' props=($(<stuff.log))
IFS='\n' props=($(printf "%s\n" "${props[@]}" | sed 's/^"//;s/"$//'))
```

Anyway I think I would hesitate to use such method in production code. Would be better to write a proper fully parser that takes `"` into account and reads input char by char.

If you want to read a file into an array, use `mapfile` or `readarray` commands (they are exactly the same command).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I couldn't understand what to do with this. Sorry I'm really new to bash. Can you give me a working example, if you don't mind?

Comment: Oh, I see. And seems like I'm able to pick any element I want with like `echo "${props[i+2]}"` however this goes in an order so for example, for the `50th` item, I have to use `echo "${props[I+50]}"`, right? And since because I will have around 120 lines in the array file and 3 columns for each line so would this be convenient to use? I was thinking about something like reading each line with 3 increments and choosing each element of each line with `${props[i]}`, `${props[I+1]}` and `${props[i+2]}` so I can only use `i0, 1 and 2` instead of like using `i+120` for the first item of 120th line.

Comment: There are many online pages explaining how arrays in bash work. To access 50th element in a `props` array yo use `${props[49]}`. If `i` is a integer value, ex. `i=5`, then `${props[i + 1]}` first expands `i+1` into `5+1`, calls `epxr` to calculate it (result= 6), and then calls `${props[6]}` after the expansion. `i have 120 lines ... 3 columns` - then choose the abstraction accordingly. Bash does not have 2D arrays. I wouldn't advise to store anything in bash arrays, they are slow, do all the parsing you need using standard unix tools (`comm`, `join` `awk` `sed` `cut` etc.)

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should use them. Thanks.